# Conditional format based on non-blank previous cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I need to conditionally format cells in a row based on the prior non-blank cell

```
A    B    C    D    E    F    G
     AC             BW        IN
BW        BC        ST        IN
```

Because B1 is AC, i want C1 and D1 to have a conditional format (changed fill which will match the format in B1). That ends when i get to E1 and the value BW. On row 2 i want to ignore b2 and only format d2.

The values in that will turn the formatting on come from a list of values i.e. AC, BC, IC, SC.

currently i have conditional formatting that looks for the list and can format the individual cell but i don't understand how to create a vlookup type of event in the conditional formatting formula field, nor how to find the first non-blank to check

Edit: added the F and G columns to show that i want C1 and D1 to format but not F1 or F2, just the blank cells after the AC or BC.

Comment: there is an Excel template for Projects that uses conditional formatting in that way; recommend you open that and play with it.  The Template is "Gantt project planner" and can be accessed by File-->New menu.

Answer (score 0):

Use Aggregate:

```
=AND(COLUMN(A:A)>AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A1:$E1)/(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A1:$E1,{"AC","BC","IC","SC"},0))),1),A1="")
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I'm trying to figure out the formula by breaking it down piece by piece.

Was this suppose to go into the cell or the conditional format formula (it doesn't work in either for me).

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong approach. The real question is here Copy format of previous cell in conditional formatting as all that is necessary is to copy the format from a previous cell. This way is too complex.