# Copy format of previous cell in conditional formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

My original question was [Conditional format based on non-blank previous cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46748295/conditional-format-based-on-non-blank-previous-cell)
but i now realize that it was the wrong way to go. I don't need to format based on what the prior value was, just if the cell is blank copy the format from the previous cell.

I need to conditionally format a blank cell based on the previous cell

```
A    B    C    D    E    F    G
     AC             BW        IN
BW        BC        ST        IN
```

B1 has a conditional format based on the value AC. C1 is blank so it should get the B1 format. D1 is blank and should get the C1 format. E1 is nonblank so it gets whatever the conditional format is.

The values in that will turn the formatting on come from a list of values i.e. AC, BC, IC, SC.

What i don't understand is how to copy, in the formula itself, the value of the previous format.

Comment: I would agree, but the one who makes the decision doesn't. Sure i can format paint, but it's a large sheet and just takes too much time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a formula in conditional formatting that looks for the previous non blank value, e.g. if the cell should be formatted if it's equal to one of AC, BC, IC, SC....**or if it's blank and the previous value is in that list**

Use Name Manager to define a name for your list of values e.g. make

List ={AC","BC","IC","SC"}

Now use the following formula in conditional formatting for a range starting at A1

`=MATCH(LOOKUP("zzz",$A1:A1),List,0)`

This works for text values

Comment: This doesn't quite do what i'm looking for. I just want, when a cell is blank to copy the format from the previous cell. Don't need lookups in the blank cell as that happened with the previous non-blank cell.

Comment: If it works does it matter how it's done? You won't be able to do what you suggest with simple conditional formatting

Comment: You have been lucky to have your question answered by what I consider to be the top guy in Excel. There is no way short of using VBA or doing it manually to copy a format from one cell to another. If there are only four possibilities, I believe all you can do is use his formula in four different CF rules.

Comment: There are more than four and this was just the example to illustrate my issue. I'm sure i can write the VBA script but now i have to get my users to "do something" to make the formatting happen. They are a bit, shall we say, computer phobic. I really appreciate the help, I'll just have to bite the bullet and write the VBA. Thanks everyone so much for the help, especially @barryhoudini for the answer.

Comment: Bottom line, the simple item is not possible. I have to go to VBA to copy the formatting. This answer works for a small list but you end up having to have a thicket of CF rules to catch everything. So we go to VBA. I sure hope the users won't mind hitting a button :)

Comment: Is it the same format for all items on the list? It doesn't matter how long the list is - you can just use the one formula I suggested